# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: pets.user_id

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I am working on a pet registration platform, but when I click on the submit button to save the info to my database, I seem to get this error:

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: pets.user_id (SQL: insert into "pets" ("nickname", "species", "date_of_birth", "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (Tom, Male, 2009-07-30, ?, 2020-12-13 09:59:07, 2020-12-13 09:59:07))`

This is the Pets Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Pet;
use App\Models\User;

class PetsController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('create');
    }

    public function store(User $user)
    {   
        Pet::create([
            'nickname' => request('nickname'),
            'species' => request('species'),
            'date_of_birth' => request('date_of_birth'),
            'color' => request('color'),
            'description' => request('description'),
            'user_id' => $user->id
        ]);

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

This is the Model for User:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'username',
        'phone',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function pets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Pet::class);
    }
```

This is the model for Pets:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pet extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nickname','species','date_of_birth','gender','user_id'];
    
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

This is the form view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container py-5">
    <form action="/create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        @csrf

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10">
            
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <h1><strong>Add A Pet</strong></h1>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row py-4">
                    <label for="nickname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nickname</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="nickname" type="text" class="form-control @error('nickname') is-invalid @enderror" 
                            name="nickname" 
                            value="{{ old('nickname') }}"
                            placeholder="Enter the name of the animal" 
                            required autocomplete="nickname" autofocus>

                        @error('nickname')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="species" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Species</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select id="species" class="form-control @error('species') is-invalid @enderror" 
                            name="species"
                            value="{{ old('species') }}"
                            required autocomplete="species" autofocus>
                                <option disabled selected>Select species</option>
                                <option>Dog</option>
                                <option>Domestic cat</option>
                                <option>other</option>
                        </select>

                        @error('species')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row py-4">
                    <label for="date_of_birth" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Date of birth</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="date_of_birth" type="date" class="form-control @error('date_of_birth') is-invalid @enderror" 
                            name="date_of_birth" 
                            value="{{ old('date_of_birth') }}"
                            placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" 
                            required autocomplete="date_of_birth" autofocus>

                        @error('date_of_birth')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="form-group row justify-content-center" style="padding-left:108px">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                        <select id="species" class="form-control @error('species') is-invalid @enderror" 
                                name="species"
                                value="{{ old('species') }}"
                                required autocomplete="species" autofocus>
                                    <option>Unknown</option>
                                    <option>Male</option>
                                    <option>Female</option>
                        </select>
                        @error('species')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="color">Color</label>
                        <input id="color" type="text" class="form-control @error('color') is-invalid @enderror" 
                            name="color" 
                            value="{{ old('color') }}"
                            placeholder="Select color" 
                            required autocomplete="color" autofocus>
                        @error('color')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row py-4">
                    <label for="description" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Description</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="3"
                            class="form-control @error('description') is-invalid @enderror"  
                            value="{{ old('description') }}"
                            placeholder="Enter a description of the animal"></textarea>

                        @error('description')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="row col-md-6" style="margin-left:300px">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Finish</button>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-md-6 py-4" style="margin-left:430px">
                    <a href="#"><u><h4>Add Pet Later</h4></u></a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

And finally the migration for pets table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('nickname');
            $table->string('species');
            $table->date('date_of_birth');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('color')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            
        });
    }
```

Been struggling with this for quite a while now!

Here is the routes file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();


Route::get('/register/create', [App\Http\Controllers\PetsController::class, 'create']);
Route::post('/create', [App\Http\Controllers\PetsController::class, 'store']);
```

Comment: Please add routes

Comment: You are using `$user->id`. But, there is no `$user`.

Answer (score 0):

`$user` injected in method `store()` is empty `User` model without attributes, like after `$user = new User;`.

You could retrieve current user id with 2 ways:

**First:** from request.

```
public function store()
{   
    Pet::create([
        'nickname' => request('nickname'),
        'species' => request('species'),
        'date_of_birth' => request('date_of_birth'),
        'color' => request('color'),
        'description' => request('description'),
        'user_id' => request()->user()->id
    ]);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

**Second**: from auth.

```
public function store()
{   
    Pet::create([
        'nickname' => request('nickname'),
        'species' => request('species'),
        'date_of_birth' => request('date_of_birth'),
        'color' => request('color'),
        'description' => request('description'),
        'user_id' => auth()->id()
    ]);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Or `$user->pets()->create($arrayOfData);` excluding `user_id` at the end.

Comment: @IndianCoding The `request()->user()->id` is showing the following exception error: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object.. And `auth()->id()` is showing the: SQLSTATE[23000] error

Answer (score 0):

Does the pet belong to the user who is logged in? It is not clear where the User instance comes from, in the form action I don't see a user id.

If the pet belongs to the logged in user, why don't you get the id of the user with:
`Auth::user()->id;` or `Auth::id();`  or `auth()->user()->id;`

Comment: .Yes, the pet belongs to the authenticated user. And I've tried using the `auth()->user()->id` ,but it shows this error:  "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object". The others too do not work. I am a beginner in laravel, and I have been following a tutorial on basic 'crud', and the guy used the same instance on the store method.

Comment: @Stigo-rigo https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/auth-user-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object?page=1 Look for tykus's answer about auth middleware, maybe that's your problem